# Syntax error on declaring variable inside transaction in postgresql

Tags: database, postgresql, transactions

I want to create a variable inside this transaction but I'm getting 
`ERROR: syntax error at or near "DECLARE" LINE 4: DECLARE new_id INTEGER;`.

The variable needs to hold the value of the `id` of the newly created message.
This seems to be the cleanest and race condition resistant way of doing so, but I don't know how to correctly declare the variable.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED

DECLARE new_id INTEGER;
INSERT INTO messages (author) VALUES ($author) RETURNING id INTO new_id;
-- Other statements..

COMMIT;
```

Comment: `DECLARE` allowed only in [PL/pgSQL Structure,](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-structure.html) i.e. inside a function or anonymous code block.

Comment: @klin I see, I used an anonymous code block with `DO $$` and it worked.